apt-cache search not showing expected result
I tried to do apt-cache search skype
But it shows me this as a result:
libopuso - opus codec runtime library

So what does that mean?

Does this answer your question? How do I search for available packages from the command-line?

The result tells me Skype for desktop is not a deb file. Per the Skype site, the install file is a snap. Suggest you download and install the snap file from Skype.
https://www.skype.com/en/get-skype/download-skype-for-desktop/

How do I search for available packages from the command-line?
If I understand correctly, it means that description or name of the package contains "Skype".
Indeed, libopus0 has: "Description-en: Opus codec runtime library
The Opus codec is designed for interactive speech and audio transmission over
the Internet. It is designed by the IETF Codec Working Group and incorporates
technology from Skype's SILK codec and Xiph.Org's CELT codec."
apt-cache show libopus0


You can add the --names-only option to restrict the match to package names instead of both names and descriptions
